# How do I execute an def in python from input

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

For example, I have:

```
def function():
    return
```

and I want to execute it via:

```
d = input('Enter the def name: ')
```

by entering the def name('function' in this case).

How would I do this?

===================EDIT==========================

Found the way!

```
def func():
    print('IT WORKS!')

r = raw_input('Function: ')
result = eval(r+'()')
```

Comment: You should be using `raw_input` not `input`, and you should put the function in a dictionary `{'function': function}`.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `exec()` which will execute their input.

Comment: @Scironic that is rarely (if ever) an acceptable approach

Comment: in the general case using 'exec' on user input could be a bad idea - what if i deliberately type `import os;os.system("rm *")`

Comment: I can agree that it's not necessarily a smart idea. But it is an alternative. If used it's definitely worth sanitising and restricting the input.

Comment: @Scironic and the easiest way of doing that is... using `raw_input` and only allowing choices from a dictionary

Comment: Ok, I found the way.
I actually used eval() for executing it from raw. Added the code in EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Following on @jonrsharpe's comment, you can get to a function via the module's namespace. If you are in the module with the function already, you can

```
f_name = raw_input('Enter the def name: ')
globals()[f_name]()
```

In this case, KeyError is raised if the name is not correct.

If the function is in a different module, you can

```
import functions
f_name = raw_input('Enter the def name: ')
getattr(functions, f_name)()
```

In this case, AttributeError is raised if the name is not correct.

Comment: Don't use `globals`. It exposes more than you may be expecting, potentially creating a security hole.

Comment: @Andy, it depends on the situation. The module dict is always there to play with if you'd like. For instance, unit test frameworks use it to find test cases. I use it sometimes when I don't care if the user uses the extra rope to hang himself. If input is coming from the outside world where you are worried about a DOS attack or raised privilege exploits, then yes, you'd avoid using a module dict like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function():
    print "In function"
    return

available_functions = {'function':function}
d = raw_input('Enter the def name: ')   
available_functions[d]()
```

Outputs:

```
Enter the def name: function
In function
```

Define your available functions in a dictionary. You can use this to determine if such a function exists. Then, you just need to call the that is mapped in your dictionary.

`available_functions = {'function':function}`, maps the input `function` to the function name `function`. It is called via this line: `available_functions[d]()`

If the user passed a non-existent function, you get a key error:

```
Enter the def name: nonasdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "in_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    available_functions[d]()
KeyError: 'nonasdf'
```

You can wrap a `try/except` around the `available_functions[d]()` to capture this and output a more friendly message:

```
try:
    available_functions[d]()
except KeyError:
    print "Function doesn't exist"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are several unsafe and one safe way to accomplish your goal:

```
def function():
    print "In 'function()'"
    return 7

# Unsafe way
d = input('Type "function()": ')
print "The result is",d

# Only slightly safer
d = input('Type "function": ')
d = d()
print 'The result is', d

# Safer still, but still dangerous
d = raw_input('Type "function": ')
d = vars()[d]()
print 'The result is', d

# Probably the safest way:
commands = {
    'function': function
}
def default_command():
    print "Oops"
    return 0
d = raw_input('Type "function": ')
d = commands.get(d, default_command)
d = d()
print 'The result is', d
```